# Symfony : Can not add an extra variable from my controller to twig

Tags: php, symfony, variables, twig

I have an issue with the following code:

**controller**

```
$langage = $request->request->get('langage-choisis');
$baturl = "href=\"http://localhost:8000/?keyview=".$keypreview."&order=".$numerocommande."&watch=yes"."\"";

$message = (new \Swift_Message($subject))
    ->setFrom('devdalvin@gmail.com')
    ->setTo( $destinataires)
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView('emails/contact.html.twig', [
            'IdOrder' => $langage,
            'messagegraphist' => $messagegraphist,
            'messageinvoice' => $messageinvoice,
            'baturl'=> $baturl,
            'mailinstructions' => $mailinstructions,
            'ordrefabrication' => $ordrefabrication,
            'langage' => $langage,
        ]),
       'text/html'
    );

$mailer->send($message);
```

**twig-template**

```
{% block email %}
    <p>Bonjour,
        <br/> Nos équipes ont terminées la préparation du BAT pour votre commande n°{{ IdOrder  }}.
        <br>Si votre commande comporte plusieurs articles, vous recevrez un BAT par article.
        <br>Nous soulignons que nos dates de production et d'expédition courent à date de validation du présent BAT.<br>
        {% if messagegraphiste is defined %}
            <p><b>Précision de notre service graphique : </b></p>
        <br>{{ messagegraphist  }}<br>
        {% endif %}
        <br>{{ messageinvoice | raw}} <br>
    <p><a style="color: white; padding: 20px 20px; background-color: #19692c" {{ baturl | raw}} ><b>VOIR LE BAT</b></a></p>
    <br>{{ mailinstructions | raw}}<br>
    Notre équipe vous souhaite une agréable journée.
    </p>
{{ langage }}
{% endblock %}
```

[This th error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh2Ow.png)

What is incomprehensible is that I can not add additional variable without having this error. However, I gave $langage as a value to the variable 'IdOrder' and it works. But when I want to add a variable in my table: impossible. I also tried to give another value to 'langage' (like $orderfabrication) but it remains undefined while 'orderfabrication' does work. Anyone have an idea? Thank you :)

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code of the controller ? what does the dump($langage) display ?

Comment: @letibelim the code provided suffices to demonstrate the problem

Comment: please show the (complete) `emails/contact.html.twig`. I suspect that the variable you added is somehow out of scope by probably not using *just* block but some nested block/include/embed/extend

Comment: (also show included / embedded templates).

Comment: @DarkBee It is rather an unhelpful comment. Even if it is the case, It can help others out by avoiding them to make assumptions about the code that is omitted. And the question hasn't had an answer yet so there is no arm in seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: There is no use in posting the full controller as you can clearly see `OP` is passing the variables towards twig. The reason I did not post an answer is, that it should work as is. Also `$langage` contains the correct value, as `OP` verified the value by assigning it to `IdOrder`.

Comment: Probably you should clean the cache

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. However, I already thought about cleaning the cache. In addition this is the entirety of my email / contact.html.twig file.
The dump was also used to check the value of $ language which is well defined (Checked in contact.html.twig with $ IdOrder).
So, I'm trying to clean the computer.